# how to position an image on top of another "card"?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first time here
I face a little problem which is the image that I wanted to put on top of the card do not work properly, the rest of it didn't display
I used (stack & positioned)
What should I do ??
*Note : I'm beginner* 
this is the code :

```
SizedBox(
                  width: 500,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                      child: Card(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                          child: Stack(children: [
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 40,
                              left: 150,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                child: ClipOval(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/guy.jpg",
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                radius: 50,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                          elevation: 10),
                    ),
                  )),
```

and this is the the output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAemx.png)
and i wanted to be like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxxuT.png)

Comment: Use Stack widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer for thar Stack class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
 Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 320,
                      width: 420,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Your Other Widgets',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      child: DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: AssetImage(
                              'assets/images/1.png',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want like that, then you need to put SizedBox and add size (height and or width) on it it acts as invicible widget to put space on it.

```
Stack
--Positioned (top 0)
----Column
------SizedBox (add height here around 50x50 px)
------Image (100x100 px)
--Card
```